# Will the Unicoins be valuable as Bitcoins?

Tags: discussion, unicoins

Can Unicoins valuable as Bitcoins in the future?
How long do you think is gonna happen?

Answer (score 8):

Unicoins will certainly replace Bitcoins very soon. Since the creation algorithm is based on user interaction it is much saver than that of bitcoin - which relys on mathematics noone really understands. I give Bitcoins less than 2 months from now!

Answer (score 3):

Wait. What are BitCoins?

You see, Unicoins have already taken over BitCoin. The attack on Mt. Gox was led by Jon Skeet riding on a horde of Unicorns up the tall Mountain of Gox. BitCoins are silly and based on bits and bytes. Your unicoins are real thingies kept inside rock, and backed by the Reputation Standard<sup>TM</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Unicoins<sup>SX</sup> are much more valuable then any other electronic currency. Beside electronicity, it is the most valuable cuurency ever existed!

Do you know any other kinda of money/currency that you *mined* from rock by mouse?

Answer (score 1):

More so.  BitCoins allow automated mining, whereas the only way to get Unicoins is via massive clicking - at least until they fix the technical issues that let you exchange boring government-issued currency for them.  All of that manual labor of well-paid (compared to global averages) technology workers adds up to some serious input costs to generate Unicoins.  Since worth often a factor of input costs, it stands to reason that Unicoins are much more valuable than BitCoins.

Unless you power your BitCoin mining rig with pedal-power.